# Can I update jQuery DataTable (1.10) data sourced from AJAX?

Tags: datatables

I have a data table (1.10) pulling data down via AJAX from the server. It's not using server-side processing, it gets the whole data set and manipulates it locally in the browser. I need to then update the data and send it back up later on. I'm at the manipulating part but can't figure out how to do it. What I need to do is update the data for a cell, refresh the table locally, and after the user is done changing things use that data in a POST to save it.

I've been able to update the data in a few ways including:

```
$('#dt').dataTable().api().row().data().Code="foo"
$('#dt').dataTable().api().rows().data()[0].Code="foo"
```

I can see the new data when I do something like:

```
$('#dt').dataTable().api().rows().data()
```

However if I call `draw()` it doesn't update the table.

The only thing I can think of is to remove AJAX from the equation. I could pull the data down separately and just have the data table use a local array, manipulate the array outside of the table (though it seems I'm doing this successfully already) and redraw or destroy/recreate it... It seems like this should be possible, but maybe not with an AJAX data source.

P.S. I think there should be a jquery-datatables-1.10 tag since the usage can be significantly different between versions.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, sorry, I just found this gem in the [docs](http://datatables.net/reference/api/data%28%29):

> If you modify the data contained in the returned array, ensure that you use the rows().invalidate()DT, columns().invalidate()DT or any of the other invalidation methods to cause DataTables to notice the change and re-read the data source.

This solved my problem:

```
$('#dt').dataTable().api().rows().invalidate().draw()
```